# Ubuntu 16.04 Firefox and software OS updates stopped working

Tags: 16.04, firefox, software-center, system

Was working fine, suddenly Firefox and software center OS updates stopped working I have googled and tried all answers I can find listed in *Ask Ubuntu*.  The questions I have researched indicate a possible ivp6 issue and suggest disabling it- 
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled Firefox
- I have added lines to sysctl

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then in terminal-

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

I found a reference to bind9 but despite a search could find no such file so I installed it

still no luck - I have been trying for 2 days now please help

Error message in browser is:

> The connection has timed out

The server at www.xxxxxxx.com is taking too long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It might be showing you the message "Server not found" despite your internet is working its easy to fix

1. sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
2. sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service

   OR

   sudo systemctl restart network.service
3. Reboot

Comment: @Graham - tried all 3 options - none worked - No3 returned 'Failed to restart network.service: Unit network.service not found.'

Comment: Still trying to solve it please help!

Comment: Have you tried setting the DNS ? 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4  also try new DNS 1.1.1.1 that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your DNS servers to your modem IP and Google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) This option is located in System Settings > Network on the IPV4 tab. To add DNS servers, click on the small icon on the right of the DNS server field. and reboot.

Comment: @ Jatin-CBS Sorry, I cannot see an IPV4 tab in Ubuntu 16.04 under system settings / network

Comment: Still looking for solution please anybody?